# with what tools you should be familiar with - is it a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence

with what tools you should get familiar with - is it a correct sentence? Is it correct to use a word with at the beginning and end of the sentence?

Comment: Are you asking a question about the tools? If so, it's, "***With** what tools **should you** get familiar?*" OR "*What tools **should you** get familiar **with**?*" You can't have "with" at the start and the end.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to use with twice.

You can say "What tools should you get familiar with?"  (note the inversion to "should you" to form the question, not "you should".) Or, more formally "With what tools should you get familiar?"  And consider using "which" instead of "what", if the types of tools are known in advance:  "With which tools should you be familiar?"